# Is it possible to type cast to a parent abstract class?

Tags: java, casting, abstract-class, classcastexception

I'm in the process of porting a C# project into Java. I've got a chunk of code that looks like this:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract void foo() throws Exception;
    public abstract void bar();
}
```

And then, elsewhere...

```
public class FirstOuterClass {
    public class FirstInnerClass extends A {
                  // defines foo() and bar()
    }
}
```

Further elsewhere...

```
public class SecondOuterClass {    
     public class SecondInnerClass extends A {
                  // defines foo() and bar()
    }
}
```

And finally, even MORE elsewhere....

```
HashMap<Type, A> handlers = new HashMap<Type, A>();
        for (Entry e : HashMapOfStringToEntry.getTypes())
        {       
            if(e.Handler != null) {
                handlers.put(e.Type, (A) e.Handler);
            }
        }
```

e.Handler can be either a type of FirstInnerClass or SecondInnerClass. It's that conversation e.Handler to (A) that is causing the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class
```

I've verified with debugging output that e.Handler is indeed a class type of FirstOuterClass$FirstInnerClass. So either there are differences in casting between C# & Java (possible) or I am not providing the right syntax somewhere (also possible).

(I'm sorry for not pasting the whole code, like what the HashMaps are for. I don't want to muddle up the real issue. Basically it's a mapping between a String key and a couple of classes that extend abstract A.)

Comment: It looks fine, though why is e.Handler's static type not A so you avoid the cast, and get the problem at its source?

Comment: Can you provide more data on HashMapOfStringToEntry? your foreach loop is confusing. Map returns Entry<Key, Value> and you're using something else. It looks like it returns a local implementation of Entry which may help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of your inner classes was failing to cast to `A`, then your exception would look like:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: FirstOuterClass$FirstInnerClass cannot be cast to A

Instead, you're getting this:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class

Are you cutting off "cannot be cast to A" at the end of this?

Regardless, it appears that `e.Handler` is of type `java.lang.Class`.  As in, `FirstOuterClass$FirstInnerClass` itself rather than a single instance of it.

Comment: You're right, but I don't know why. If I do an instanceof check on e.Handler, I get it set to java.lang.Class--it's not identifying itself as a subclass...

Comment: Actually, I think I got it, and it's just as you said. I don't have an instantiation of the object; I'm just passing e.Handler.class, in effect. Is there a way to compare class inheritance for non-instantiated objects?

Comment: Figured it out. Needed my classes to implement java.lang.reflect.Type and instantiate the classes as objects correctly. Sorry for the 3 comments, I can't seem to edit mine. Marking as answer. THANK YOU!

Comment: @GJT: You can only edit comments for a short time after you submit them.  After the editing period ends, remember that you can still delete your own comments at any time.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception message, it appears that you are trying to cast an instance of `Class`, not an instance of the class it represents.